# Regex in PHP expecting to match strings like "${string}" not working

Tags: php, regex

I’ve got:

```
$ap=0;
$matches=array();
d($ap, $vv[$value],$matches);
$ap = preg_match("/\$[({].+[)}]/", $vv[$value], $matches);
d($ap, $vv[$value],$matches);
```

`d()` is a custom function like `var_dump()`.

When `$vv[$value]` is "exec_prefix = ${prefix}", why is that `$ap` is `0`, and there’s no matches ($matches is still an empty array)?

I am expecting "${prefix}" to be matched.

I tried the regex in regexpal.com and it matches too.

Answer (score 2):

In your regex, you are trying to use `$` as the start of field marker.  As PHP needs the `$` to be escaped otherwise it will think it's introducing a variable substitution (in double quotes) it will use the `\` you've included for this purpose.  BUT this then leaves the regex as

```
/$[({].+[)}]/
```

and this means it will use the `$` as the end of string marker - and therefore not find the content your after.

So, you need a second escape before the dollar to make sure it is picked up properly...

```
$ap = preg_match("/\\$[({].+[)}]/", $vv[$value], $matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

The "\" before "$" is removed before it gets to preg_match() because it is treated by PHP as an escape character for "$".

To fix this, simply use single quote instead of double quote:

```
$ap = preg_match('/\$[({].+[)}]/', $vv[$value], $matches);
```